# Database Design: Referencing multiple connected tables

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I am sorry for the vague title but I have no idea how to pin down my problem that precisely...

My question is based on the following condition:

A table called "components" containing some components with their additional information

A table called "specifications" containing some specifications with their additional information where each specification belongs to exactly one component 
 
Up to now, I followed a standard ONE-TO-MANY approach using the ID of "components" as a foreign key in "specifications". Now, here is my problem: I'd like to have **a third table** called "scenarios" which stores in each row - amongst other information - for each possible component in "components" exactly one of the specifications belonging to this component. How can I do this? 
 
 One approach I thought of was adding a column into "scenarios" for each component - like this:

```
--------------------------------
| component_id | component_name |
--------------------------------
|   1          |   C1           |
|   2          |   C2           |
--------------------------------

-------------------------------------------------------
| specification_id | component_id | specification_name |
-------------------------------------------------------
|   1              |   1          |   S1               |
|   2              |   1          |   S2               |
|   3              |   2          |   S3               |
|   4              |   2          |   S4               |
-------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| scenario_id | specification_id_for_component_with_id_1 | specification_id_for_component_with_id_2 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1         |   2                                      |   3                                      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But I'd like to make sure that the specifications actually exist & belong to the referenced component. In addition, for each new component the "scenarios" table had to be altered. There has to be a better approach...

Comment: Put a unique index on the component field and a composite index on Component / specification.  This way a component can only be listed once; and it can only be listed with one specification.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, I'm afraid I didn't yet get it... I already have ID columns as primary keys in both "components" and "specifications". Where should I put the composite index?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're after.  I thought you wanted a scenario which for each component only allowed a single specification be listed.  So a Unique index on component with a composite index on component_ID and specification_ID would ensure a component only could have 1 specification in the scenario table.

Comment: Please give a [mcve] for as much of this as possible. You described a table so what is the problem with just creating it? Do you mean, how do you enforce that only valid component-specification pairs appear in it? Please edit to be clear.

Comment: I hope the added example illustrates my problem in a better way. Yes, I want to enforce that only valid component/specification pairs can be added. I also want to prevent that the "scenarios" table has to be altered with each new component. So I am also asking for the structure of the "scenarios" table.